# Execution context of a .lnk created on desktop

Tags: c#, execution, shortcut-file

I've an application A that create a shortcut on Desktop linked to another application B. Application B on start have to check if some files need to be updated and download it to B application folder but if I open it from the shortcut on  desktop, Application B download all the updated files on the desktop. I've searched for answer if there's a way to tell the created link just to don't change the execution context.

The code that create .lnk on desktop is the following:

```
Type t = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("72C24DD5-D70A-438B-8A42-98424B88AFB8")); //Windows Script Host Shell Object
        dynamic shell = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
        try
        {
            var lnk = shell.CreateShortcut(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)+"/"+string.Format("{0}.lnk", Name));
            try
            {
                lnk.TargetPath = Path;
                lnk.IconLocation = Path+", 0";
                lnk.Save();
            }
            finally
            {
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(lnk);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(shell);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link isn't the problem. The execution context is always the current working directory.

In your B program you have to specify the folder of B to write to. You can get the current applications path using:

```
using System.Reflection;

string path = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
```

That is the path of the exe. To get the directory, you can wrap it:

```
using System.IO;

string folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
```

Comment: Thank you! this is working fine. I was trying to better undestand the shortcut behaviour but i think this is the better way to solve this problem. Cheers!